# Filter a 2d array using multiple conditions

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, conditional-statements, filtering

I have an array of arrays and I need to implement a combination of filters in order to achieve the desires results.

From a select fields, I take the data to be able to filter the results.

I need to show all the results that contain both filters.

```
<select name="filter">
    <option value="1">apple</option>
    <option value="2">pear</option>
</select>
<label>Combine</label>
<select name="filter2">
    <option value="1">melon</option>
    <option value="2">strawberry</option>
</select>

foreach ($complete as $subdime) {
    $substr = $filter;
    $substr2 = $filter2;
    if (
        $filter !== 'total'
        && strpos($subdime[0], $substr) !== false
        && $filter2 === ""
    ) {
        / * print result */
    }
}
```

With one filter, everything works.
If instead I insert an AND to visualize both, the vector is empty.

```
if (
    $filter !== 'total'
    && strpos($subdime[0], $substr) !== false
    && strpos($subdime[0], $substr2) !== false
) {
```

My goal would be to be able to print the results that correspond to both filters at the same time.

The `$complete` array:

```
[
    1 => [
        '(apple)'
        '(not set)', 
        20191001,
        123456,
        'cereal'
    ],
    2 => [
        '(apple)',
        '(not set)',
        20191001,
        7894561,
        'cacao'
    ],
    3 => [
        '(melon)',
        '(not set)',
        20191002,
        123489,
        null
    ],
    4 => [
        '(pear)',
        '(not set)',
        20191002,
        365478,
        'cacao'
    ],
    5 => [
        '(pear)',
        '(not set)',
        20191002,
        1697823,
        'banana'
    ],
    6 => [
        '(strawberry)',
        '(not set)',
        20191002,
        6578931,
        null
    ]
```

Comment: Currently it looks as if you are searching the first item in each of the sub arrays, looking for your filter in a string.  So given your form, you have a filter string of say '1' and are looking for that in a string.  Given the data you have supplied searching the string '(melon)' for a digit will never match.  What are you trying to match?

Comment: I would like to print all the values that correspond at the same time to both the value of filter 1 and those of filter 2

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'd solve it by creating an array out the two filters and check the value using 'in_array'
like so:

```
$filters = [$filter1,$filter2];
        foreach ($complete as $index => $subdime) {
            if(in_array($subdime[0],$filters)){
                // value matches one of the filters - do something
            }
        }
```